# randomly generate 40 questions in vb6? please help me

Tags: vb6, random

i've been trying to create a vb6 code that will randomize 10 questions but it's not working. i use sql as my database

here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
Dim real_ans As String
Dim nCnt As Integer
'nCnt = nCnt + 2
'Label3.Caption = nCnt
real_ans = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("answer")
 With Adodc2.Recordset
 Dim grade As String

If (real_ans = "A" And Option1.Value = True) Or (real_ans = "B" And Option2.Value = True) Or (real_ans = "C" And Option3.Value = True) Or (real_ans = "D" And Option4.Value = True) Then
    .Fields("english_score").Value = .Fields("english_score").Value + 1
     nEnglish_score = Adodc2.Recordset.Fields("english_score").Value
     Select Case nEnglish_score
Case Is >= 7 'If score above 80...
    grade = "genius" 'Give an A
    With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
    End With
Case Is >= 6 'If score above 70...
    grade = "Superior " 'Give a B
     With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
    End With
Case Is >= 5 'If score above 60...
    grade = "High Average" 'Give a C
     With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
    End With
Case Is >= 4 'If score above 50...
    grade = "Average" 'Give a D
     With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
    End With
Case Is >= 3 'If score above 40...
    grade = "Low Average " 'Give a E
     With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
    End With
Case Is >= 2 'If score above 30...
    grade = "Moron" 'Give a F
     With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
    End With
Case Is >= 1 'If score above 20...
    grade = "Idiot " 'Give a G
     With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
    End With
Case Else 'Else
    grade = "xxxx" 'Give a G
     With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
     .Update
    End With
End Select

     End If
    Adodc1.Recordset.MoveNext
    End With



End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
frmExam2.Show
frmExam2.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Initialize()
Command1.Enabled = False
With Adodc2.Recordset
.AddNew
.Fields("name").Value = cStudent_Name
.Fields("section").Value = cStudent_Section
.Fields("english_score").Value = "0"
.Fields("math_score").Value = "0"
.Fields("abstract").Value = "0"
.Fields("total_average").Value = "0"
.Fields("IQ").Value = "0"
.Update
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Change()
If Text1.Text <> "" Then
cmdNext.Enabled = True
Else
Command1.Enabled = True
 cmdNext.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

Please help me i cant  figure out whats wrong.

Comment: An error description is always nice in these types of questions :)

Comment: there's no error i dont know how to random the questions

Comment: where is the code that actually pulls the 10 questions from the database?

Comment: Mmm .. If there's no error, why are you posting it here? :P An error doesn't need to be an exception or similar, just describe what happens when you run the code contra what you expected would happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep what's the error message?

1. you don't save any space with this 'with':

```
With Adodc2.Recordset
    .Fields("IQ").Value = grade
End With
```

2. you can remove that block of code to the end (after End Select), since its in every Case statement anyway. 
   So compress it down to:

```
Adodc2.Recordset.Fields("IQ").Value = grade
```

3. why not have your option values and answers stored in the same way so you can just do a single comparison, like:
   if real_ans = OptionValue then ...

for random numbers, try this:

```
Function Rand(max As Long, Optional Min As Long) As Long

        Dim s As Single
        s = Rnd(1) * (max - Min + 1) + Min - 0.5
        Rand = CLng(Round(s, 0))


End Function
```

and  put RANDOMIZE in your form_load